# How to make RMI services available, only after application is UP and running?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, rmi

In my Spring application, I'm using an `application-rmi-context.xml` for RMI configuration and importing it into the `spring-application-context.xml`.

It makes the RMI available as soon as server is starting up and spring context is loaded, and my application is still in progress of getting completely up and running but RMI is already available.

But I need to make the RMI available only when my application is fully up and running.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You can use it like this:

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        classpath:spring/application-context.xml 
        classpath:spring/rmi-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
```

The same problem exist for me too.I solved it like this. You may also use the displacherServlet too for this

Comment: @Jayshsamaiya , I need to do it by dispatcher servlet, can you point me to dispatcherservlet solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way by using Dispatcher servlet

```
  <servlet>
          <servlet-name>rmi-services</servlet-name>
          <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
          <init-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>classpath:spring/rmi-context.xml</param-value>
          </init-param>
          <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

load-on-startup means when you want to load it in sequence